# What alternatives do I have for open source RTSP streaming player

Tags: rtsp-client

Is there anything besides VLC? 
I need to develop a youtube player without using a flash plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some open source rtsp implementations:

```
Name         Client/Server  Language  URL
live.com     C/S            C++       http://www.live555.com
darwin       S              C++       http://www.opensource.apple.com/darwinsource/
VLC          C              C         http://www.videolan.org
mplayer      C              C         http://www.mplayerhq.hu
omsp         C/S            C         http://streaming.polito.it/
              Fenice is server
              NeMeSI is client
spook        S              C         http://www.litech.org/spook/
MPEG4IP      C              C         http://www.mpeg4ip.net/
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one in C# -> http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

That library has a RtspClient and a RtspServer.

To play the RtspStream that is all you need...

To render the output you will need something to decode the payload of the RtpPackets.

If the format is JPEG you can also use my library.

If the format is not JPEG you can use FFMPEG to get JPEG's and send them out over the libraries RtspServer to clients.

Check out the CodeProject article..

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

If you need anything else let me know!